# Python, wait until network interface is up?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a python script which opens a port and listens to it on Raspberry. I added it to `/etc/rc.local` 
and everything is working properly. But my problem is the socket which is not created when the process is being executed.

```
s = socket.socket()      
s.bind((host_ip,port)) #e.g. host_ip='192.168.1.32' , port=12345
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c,addr = s.accept()
    c.send('ACK')
    c.close()
```

the above code is not executed because there is no 'eth0' connection available. What should I do? Should I loop scan the socket status until connection is being available? Is there any other more sophisticated solution?

Comment: what does you mean "eth0"

Comment: I am using ethernet to connect my device to network.

Comment: Please show the errors you get.

Comment: @boardrider, I tried to direct the log to a file, but it was left blank!

Comment: "if iface is up", "if dhcp is OK", "if net is OK" all are different. But you want do allthings with python, use `netifaces` and `urllib`.

Comment: @dsgdfg, for instance, when I halt the execution of that part of my code for 5 seconds, it works. I guess it roots network connection establishment. Does't it?

Comment: try to open url with `urllib`(request to modem interface or any web server).

Comment: @dsgdfg, how does it help me? You mean I send a request to a url and wait for response. What if there is no connection to invoke?

Comment: try something along the line `python whatever.py 2>&1 | tee -a  /tmp/log.txt` which should write both stdout and stderr to the terminal _and_ to a log file.

Comment: Try binding to `0.0.0.0` this means you are effectively binding to all interfaces including loopback.  If your using DHCP and an explicit ip for the bind, then you can't open the socket if the ip is not what you expected.  So your preamble before calling bind with an explicit IP , would be to find out the ip address on eth0 before binding.

Comment: @TimHoffman, that's is. It solved my problem and I will use it in future. Binding to 0.0.0.0 was everything I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
import urllib2,thread
from time import sleep
import netifaces


class _check:
    def __init__(self):
        self.uri="http://www.google.com"
        self.period = 5
        self.status = False
        self.ifaces()
    def check(self):
        try:
            answ = urllib2.urlopen(self.uri)
            if answ:
                self.status = True
                #Now can run your awesome code !
                print "okay go take a beer"
        except Exception,e : print e

    def timer(self,pass_arg) :
        while True :
            if   self.status != True :
                self.check()
                sleep(self.period)
                print "running"
            elif   self.status == True :
                print "thread ending"
                break
    def ifaces(self):
        for i in netifaces.interfaces() :
            try:
                print i,netifaces.ifaddresses(i)[2]
            except:
                print i, "iface not up !"


check = _check()
thread.start_new_thread(check.timer,(None,))
```

so this answer equal to my comment answer.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it. But, it raises another question. I can't guarantee the internet connection to fetch google.com. I also don't know what is the range of IP DHCP assigns to me. Does it change your answer?

Answer (score 0):

`accept()` is method will block the thread,when no device is detected connecting server,it will block, means the code after `accept()` will not executed.

Comment: my problem corresponds to binding process, before my device negotiation with DHCP server, the binding process starts. I know I can wait for a valid IP address then start binding, but I'm looking for a more sophisticated method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Python but generally speaking of socket programming.

1. When you listen you don't need any host (`s.bind(('',port))`).
2. You have to determine a function or an event handler that raises when a connection is established (maybe `handle_connect` in Python).
3. In the handler function you connect the client on a port other than the port you are currently listening.